# What is the Python equivalent of these Haskell higher-order functions?

Tags: python, haskell

The chapter on Partial Functions from the book [Learn You a Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) contains the following code:

```
multThree :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
multThree x y z = x * y * z

ghci> let multTwoWithNine = multThree 9
ghci> multTwoWithNine 2 3
54
ghci> let multWithEighteen = multTwoWithNine 2
ghci> multWithEighteen 10
180
```

I am currently playing with the functools library in Python, and managed to replicate the behavior of those functions using it.

```
from functools import partial

def multThree(x,y,z):
  return x * y * z

>>> multTwoWithNine = partial(multThree,9)
>>> multTwoWithNine(2,3)
>>> multWithEighteen = partial(multTwoWithNine,2)
>>> multWithEighteen(10)
180
```

One thing I would now like to do is see if I can replicate some of the more interesting higher-order functions from the same book chapter, such as:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' _ [] _ = []
zipWith' _ _ [] = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this, or if `partial()` is even useful here.

Comment: You should edit and fix your functions, making sure they are all syntactically correct.  Your first, for example, is missing its arguments.

Comment: Technically you'd have to use `partial` in any conversion, since all Haskell functions are automatically curried, and `partial` emulates the ability curried functions have to be partially applied. Or you can write the python versions as curried functions, but then you have to call them like `foo(a)(b)(c)`.

Comment: Minor note: you want "partially applied functions" not "partial functions".

Answer (score 5):

Python's built-in `map` function behaves like Haskell's `zipWith`:

```
>>> def add(x,y): return x + y
... 
>>> map(add,[1,2,3],[10,20,30])
[11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: map is built in and not defined in a library?

Comment: I guess I am hoping for an explaination as to why it is (must be?) built in.

Comment: Historical reasons: `map` has been a builtin function for a long time, dating back to at least the 1.x releases in the mid-90's.  `functools` and `itertools` are much more recent additions and reflect a newer philosophy of adding functionality through separate modules and packages in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 6, 7, 8]

>> map(add, x, y)
[6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Also, do check out the Python builtin `itertools` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

This Python code acts similar to the `zipWith'` function you gave:

```
def zip_with(f, l1, l2):
    if len(l1) == 0 or len(l2) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [f(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip_with(f, l1[1:], l2[1:])
```

This function has a couple of shortcomings, though, compared with the Haskell function. The first is that it doesn't look as nice, because Python doesn't have pattern matching syntax; we have to use `len`, `[0]`, and `[1:]` instead. The second is that the Python function does not use lazy evaluation in any way, so `zip_with` will always go through the entire list, even when it could get away with stopping early. The third is that this function calls itself once for every element of the resulting list, and Python has a recursion limit of about (or exactly?) 1,000, so this function will raise an exception if the output list is more than about 1,000 elements long.

The second and third problems could be solved using generators instead.

Comment: You can also use `[f(l1.pop(),l2.pop())] + zip_with(f, l1, l2)` and so no need for ugly `[0]` or `[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate to use built-in [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and list comprehension:

```
>>> zip_with = lambda fn, la, lb: [fn(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(la, lb)]

>>> add2 = lambda x,y: x+y
>>> zip_with(add2, range(10), range(1,11))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```